# Displaying the selected value in Ext.button.Split button

Tags: javascript, extjs

From this example i.e.,

```
 Ext.create('Ext.button.Split', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    text: 'Options',
    // handle a click on the button itself
    handler: function() {
        alert("The button was clicked");
    },
    menu: new Ext.menu.Menu({
        items: [
            // these will render as dropdown menu items when the arrow is clicked:
            {text: 'Item 1', handler: function(){ alert("Item 1 clicked"); }},
            {text: 'Item 2', handler: function(){ alert("Item 2 clicked"); }}
        ]
    })
});
```

How would you dynamically display the selection in the button?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you can use ```beforeShow``` function of a menu which called before showing menu item so here you can get the selected value and set the text of a button. hope it will help u

Comment: Is this what you want? [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2if7)

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm new, how do I marked that as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You must get to grandparent and set the text, heres's the fiddle: [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2if7)